# Bateman equations result for U235 with & without MOX

Tags: nuclear-physics

I would like to **get the values** of the Bateman equations result of the following picture :

[image]

This picture comes from the following page : https://www.radiation-dosimetry.org/fr/quest-ce-que-lequation-de-bateman-desintegration-radioactive-definition/

It seems that the Pu242 is also missing.

**Is there a way to get a csv file of the istotopic composition from 0 to 60 MWd/kg ?**

**Is it possible to get also the values for a U235 fuel with MOX ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your image is an example of what can be obtained from isotopic evolution calculation codes.

There are many parameters to take into account: power, neutron spectrum, neutron fluxes , activation cross sections, irradiation diagram, etc.
These codes are complex to implement by specialists in neutron calculations and require significant calculation means. It is impossible to obtain the detail of the calculation of each point: it is a complex result of the calculation code .

A sample code: https://info.ornl.gov/sites/publications/Files/Pub52057.pdf

The formation of 242Pu is weak since it depends on the quantity of 241Pu present: it is neglected in your image.

Comment: Exactly what I needed!

Comment: I have a few first questions about this report. 

1- Is there a difference between TU (ton of uranium) and TIHM (ton of initial heavy metal). Maybe some metal components in the packaging is taken into account. 

2- In many graphics, the measures are compared with the ORIGEN PWR (2.5, 3.5 and 4.5 %). Is there a way to get the table of the simulation result values ?

Thanks

Comment: In my opinion, there is no difference between TU and TIHM if the fuel is enriched 235U, but obviously this is no longer true for MOX fuel.
Here, a very precise drawing of the evolution of the fuel 235U enriched with 3%, on which you can note numerical values.
Still in my opinion, these values are proportional to the enrichment in the case of enriched 235U fuel (non-MOX).
https://supernovae.in2p3.fr/~llg/Enseignements/5P801/documents/09-Evolution-du-Combustible.pdf
If you do a thorough search you may find tables of values but I don't know of any immediately.

Comment: In addition, on this same document, you find basic equations of isotopic evolution.